# Case class hashCode and equals override optional attributes

Tags: scala

How to override hashcode and equals method if it's all attributes are optional, I tried below, what's the better way to write hashCode and equals

```
case class A(id: Option[String], name: Option[String]){
  override def hashCode(): Int = ???

  override def canEqual(a: Any) = a.isInstanceOf[A]

  override def equals(obj: Any): Boolean = obj match {
    case obj: A => {
      obj.canEqual(this) && this.id == obj.id && this.name == obj.name
    }
    case _ => false
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to override those methods? `case classes` already generate the correct implementation. If the default one doesn't satisfy your needs, I would suggest using a normal class instead. Finally, you are not clear with your question, what do you mean with _"better way"_? Better in which sense?

Comment: You don't need braces around the case body. Also, the case pattern is an instanceof test, so the canEqual is redundant; overriding canEqual is also redundant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do without the luxury equals if you're not boxing primitives or nulls.

That can save some null checks and instanceof/checkcast.

```
scala> case class C(id: Option[String], name: Option[String]) {
     | override def equals(other: Any) = other match { case c: C => cmp(id, c.id) && cmp(name, c.name) case _ => false }
     | private def cmp(x: Option[String], y: Option[String]): Boolean =
     | if (x eq None) y eq None else !(y eq None) && x.get.equals(y.get)
     | }
defined class C

scala> val x = C(Option("king"), Option("kong"))
x: C = C(Some(king),Some(kong))

scala> val y = C(Option("king"), Option("kong"))
y: C = C(Some(king),Some(kong))

scala> x == y
res0: Boolean = true

scala> val y = C(Option("king"), Option("king"))
y: C = C(Some(king),Some(king))

scala> x == y
res1: Boolean = false
```

But:

```
scala> val y = C(Option("king"), Some(null))
y: C = C(Some(king),Some(null))

scala> x == y
res2: Boolean = false

scala> y == x
java.lang.NullPointerException
  at C.cmp(<console>:4)
  at C.equals(<console>:2)
  ... 28 elided

scala> val y = C(Option("king"), null)
y: C = C(Some(king),null)

scala> x == y
java.lang.NullPointerException
  at C.cmp(<console>:4)
  at C.equals(<console>:2)
  ... 28 elided
```

There's not much to gain from avoiding hashCode of None, which is just `"None".##`.

Illustrating loss of some comparison:

```
scala> :pa
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

case class C(id: Option[String], name: Option[Any]) {
override def equals(other: Any) = other match { case c: C => cmp(id, c.id) && cmp(name, c.name) case _ => false }
private def cmp[A](x: Option[A], y: Option[A]) = if (x eq None) y eq None else !(y eq None) && x.get.equals(y.get)
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined class C

scala> val x = C(Option("king"), Option('k'))
x: C = C(Some(king),Some(k))

scala> val y = C(Option("king"), Option('k'.toInt))
y: C = C(Some(king),Some(107))

scala> x == y
res19: Boolean = false

scala> case class K(id: Option[String], name: Option[Any])
defined class K

scala> K(Option("king"), Option('k')) == K(Option("king"), Option('k'.toInt))
res20: Boolean = true
```